# Installation problem with Ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 on my Dell Inspiron 5520 using wubi. It makes my machine reboot, and starts installation. The problem is - as the installation comes to the step 'preaparing to install', it shows me hourglass and freezes. I waited for 4 hours once, but it never proceeds. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [Ubuntu 12.04.4](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-i386.iso.torrent) 32bit. Less problems when performing a [wubi](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe) installation especially after you boot into Ubuntu and need to install certain packages that may or may not work in Ubuntu 64bit.

Also, do not allocate more than 30GB space for your Ubuntu virtual disk because as I understand 30GB is the maximum size allowed for a wubi installation.